# Pandas expanding dataframe returning multiple values on apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way I can apply percentile function on multiple percentile values on an expanding dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(1000)

df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Data'])

val = [25,30]

df['25th_Perc'] = df.expanding(min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: np.nanpercentile(x, val, interpolation='nearest'), raw=True)
```

The code works for one value 25 but cant work on list of values [25,30] and throws the error shown below.[image]

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67492950/faster-way-to-get-fixed-percentile-on-a-expanding-dataframe/67493392#67493392

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only a solution with `numpy`:

```py
a = np.tril(df["Data"].values)
a[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0], k=1)] = np.nan
p = np.nanpercentile(a, val, interpolation="nearest", axis=1)
df[["25th_Perc", "50th_Perc"]] = p.T
```

For demo purpose only, I took a subset of your data and set percentile to `[25, 50]`:

```py
vals = [25, 50]
df1 = df.head(5).copy()
print(df)

       Data
0  0.173577
1  0.559380
2  0.634297
3  0.932697
4  0.452523
```

Get the lower triangle (equiv. `df.expanding(min_periods=1)`):

```py
a = np.tril(df1["Data"].values)
print(a)

array([[0.17357693, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.93269719, 0.        ],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.93269719, 0.45252274]])
```

Set `nan` the upper triangle, diagonal excluded (`k=1`) to ignore non applicable data:

```py
a[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0], k=1)] = np.nan
print(a)

array([[0.17357693,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673,        nan,        nan],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.93269719,        nan],
       [0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.93269719, 0.45252274]])
```

Compute percentiles:

```py
p = np.nanpercentile(a, [25, 50], interpolation="nearest", axis=1)
print(p)

array([[0.17357693, 0.17357693, 0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.45252274],   # 25th
       [0.17357693, 0.17357693, 0.55937968, 0.63429673, 0.55937968]])  # 50th
        # Row 1     # Row 2     # Row 3     # Row 4     # Row 5
```

Return to pandas:

```py
df1[["25th_Perc", "50th_Perc"]] = p.T
print(df1)

       Data  25th_Perc  50th_Perc
0  0.173577   0.173577   0.173577
1  0.559380   0.173577   0.173577
2  0.634297   0.173577   0.559380
3  0.932697   0.559380   0.634297
4  0.452523   0.452523   0.559380
```